# Matplotlib - add labelled ticks to axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

How can one add additional labelled ticks to an axis?
For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10)  # random function to plot
y = np.exp(-x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1) 
axs.plot(x,y)
axs.set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot]

I would like to have labelled y-ticks not only at the powers of 10, but also at, say, 0.15, 0.25,...

Answer (score 0):

After `axs.set_ycale("log")` you can control yticks

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10)  # random function to plot
y = np.exp(-x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1) 
axs.plot(x,y)

axs.set_yscale("log")
axs.set_yticks([np.exp(-_) for _ in np.arange(0,10,.5)])
axs.set_yticklabels([f'10^{_}' for _ in np.arange(0,10,.5)])

plt.show()
```